# setInterval within a function is doubling console.log each second - Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, datetime, duplicates, setinterval

I am still getting my head around JS and i'm starting to get it, but im struggling with setInterval. I have looked online for answers but I cannot implement a solution. **My project is a loading bar that shows how far into your shift you are at work.**

I have a setInterval for working out the distance from now to 09:00:00am per second

I have another setInterval for updating the width of the loading bar that is within a function per second

My educated guess is that both are conflicting, but I need to pass variables between the two functions so I cannot separate them. I have added a console.log that will incease from 1, 20, 50, 150, 300, 500, 700 ect. This is messing with my loading bar because after a while its trying to **loadingBar.style.width = percentage.toFixed(4) + "%";** x 1000 per second.

What am I missing?

```js
const target = 100; //percent

let shiftLength = 8.5; //hours
//convert into miliseconds
shiftLength *= 60 * (60 * 1000);

function setup() {
//Set the start point for today at 09:00:00am & now.
let start = new Date();
start.setHours(9, 00, 00);

setInterval(timeConversion, 1000);

function timeConversion() {

    //Work out the difference in miliseconds from now to the start point.
    let now = new Date();
    let distance = now -= start;

    // Time calculations for hours, minutes and seconds
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    let miliseconds = distance;

    //Percentage of the day complete
    let percentage;
    percentage = (miliseconds / shiftLength) * 100;

    moveLoadingBar();

    function moveLoadingBar() {
        let loadingBar = document.getElementById("myBar");
        let id = setInterval(frame, 1000);

        //pass the percentage to a function that updates the width of the loading bar
        function frame() {
            if (percentage >= target) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                loadingBar.style.width = percentage.toFixed(4) + "%";

                //The line above and this is being duplicated to the console.
                //the longer this code runs the more buggy my bar appears.
                console.log("hello");
            }
        }
    }
}
}

setup();
```

```css
#myProgress {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

#myBar {
  width: 1%;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #00C9FF 0%, #92FE9D 100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
       <title>Loading bar project</title>
</head>

<body>

<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar"></div>
</div>

<br>

</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `moveLoadingBar()` function starts a new interval timer each time it's called, and that happens within another interval timer callback.

Comment: What would be the best way to set both timeConversion() & frame() to execute per second at the same time? 

Use setTimeout as Pete suggested?

Comment: You keep setting a new interval of frame, but you only ever clear the interval once `percentage >= target` - you should clear it before each time you set it or use a setTimeout so it only runs once

Comment: Thanks Pete, That fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting an interval within your interval, try using `setTimeout` instead:

```js
setInterval(timeConversion, 1000); // INTERVAL

function timeConversion() {

    //Work out the difference in miliseconds from now to the start point.
    let now = new Date();
    let distance = now -= start;

    // Time calculations for hours, minutes and seconds
    let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    let miliseconds = distance;

    //Percentage of the day complete
    let percentage;
    percentage = (miliseconds / shiftLength) * 100;

    moveLoadingBar();

    function moveLoadingBar() {
        let loadingBar = document.getElementById("myBar");
        let id = setInterval(frame, 1000); // INTERVAL INSIDE INTERVAL; make this setTimeout

        //pass the percentage to a function that updates the width of the loading bar
        function frame() {
            if (percentage >= target) {
                clearInterval(id);
            } else {
                loadingBar.style.width = percentage.toFixed(4) + "%";

                //The line above and this is being duplicated to the console.
                //the longer this code runs the more buggy my bar appears.
                console.log("hello");
            }
        }
    }
```